# using python and lxml to crawl a page - (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii',

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I am using python2.7 and lxml to fetch a page. I keep getting the below errors.

```
(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'Approximate Dimensions: 4\xbd" x 4" x 7" (assembled)', 25, 26, 'ordinal not in range(128)'), <traceback object at 0x7f9198ac48c0>)
```

I have tried the following:

```
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
for el in doc.iter('h2'):
    el.text_content().decode('utf-8','ignore')
    OR
    el.text_content().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

How to I resolve these errors?  I need to be able to 1) Save to a text file then 2) upload the text file to MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
el.text_content().encode('utf-8')
```

it is unicode, and you want to store it (as text) to utf-8.

Comment: Then you'll have to give more context, i.e. a traceback and the code it refers to, and the encoding you've set for your database/table/column.

Answer (score 0):

What headers says the page use for encoding can be different from what it really is. If the page's actual encoding is not utf-8, it's a bit tricker to do the right business.

First you should look at the returned text from `el.text_content()`

`x = el.text_content()
print x`

If you still some encoded string like `/x09`, it means it's not decoded yet.

If x is unicode, (starting with 'u') you should convert `unicode` to `str` and decode it with proper encoding (like `cp1252` or sth)

`chars = ''.join([chr(ord(x)) for x in el.text_content()])
/// It will change your dumb unicode to str
result = chars.decode({try with different encoding until it doesn't throw an error})
/// now you decode str with proper format`